Existence and continuity of inverse operator
Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces. Let $T:E \to F$ is a linear operator and suppose that exists $c>0$ such that
$$\|T(x)\| \geq c \|x\|, \quad \forall x \in E.$$
Then it's easy to see that $\operatorname{ker}(T) = {0}$ and $T^{-1}:T(E)\to F$ exists. Moreover, if $y = T(x) \in T(E)$, then
$$\|T^{-1}(y)\| = \|x\| \leq \frac{1}{c}\|T(x)\| = \frac{1}{c}\|y\|.$$
Is it sufficient to prove that $T^{-1}$ is bounded (and then, continuous)? Is continuity of $T$ necessary?

What do you mean by “limited”? Do you mean bounded? And, no, a discontinuous $T$ could still have a continuous inverse. For example, on $c_{00}$ (finitely supported sequences on $\mathbb{N}$) with the sup norm, multiplication along the diagonal by $n$ is unbounded, but a $c$ as in your question still exists ($c = 1$) and in fact it does have a bounded inverse. (Namely multiplication along the diagonal by $1/n$.)

@DavidGao, you're right. The correct word is bounded.

In that case your proof is perfectly right and shows that $T^{-1}$ is bounded. You did not use $T$ is bounded anywhere in the proof, so that is unnecessary. And I’ve given a specific example showing that an unbounded $T$ could still satisfy the conditions you wrote down and therefore has a bounded inverse. So does that answer your question?

@DavidGao yes!! Thank you!
